# Custom links or pages from Media Gallery

Tags: gallery, media

I have a simple Wordpress Media Gallery running on a page and every time you click an image it takes you to the attachment page. This is fine as I can write an article in the description and that page will contain text and the main image.

The issue is I would like each image to have it's own article/post on my website. As I look at it there are two solutions I can see, but I may be missing something.

1) Use the attachment page as the article and somehow get WordPress to use these as posts.

2) Set a custom link in the gallery so that it links to an actual article.

Neither are brilliant and I would like to know if anyone knows of a better way to accomplish this.

Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated.